# what is oldroot?

Tags: arch-linux, mount, shutdown

When I shutdown my laptop there are some messages like

```
unmounting oldroot/*
```

They came after a kernel-update, just curious what this means and if I need "oldroot"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has more to do with systemd rather than the kernel, and in short, it means you just had a clean shutdown. See here : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174495 .